# How can you calculate someone's location?

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, game-theory

Suppose there are 10 people who live in different cities. And I want to know who lives where. Each time I can ask two of them 'who of you lives closer to X?' Where X is myself or another person of the group.

Is it possible to calculate the approximate locations of those 10 people with those restrictions? And if not, what questions could I ask them to be able to deduce their location without asking directly?

Comment: Do you know what the cities are, so you know the distances between them?

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes

Answer (score 1):

At the extreme, you can ask all $\frac 12(10)(11)$ pairs to compare their distances.  Assuming no city-city distances match, you can match that list to the sorted list of distances between the cities and know where everyone is.  The obvious improvement is to try to find a smaller set of comparisons that will also let you match people to cities.  I suspect that depends on where the cities are.  If one is very far from all the rest, it should be easy to identify the person who lives there.